# Multipass ubuntu VPN

Tags: vpn, ubuntu-multipass

After logging into the NordVPN client the VM disconnects and becomes unreachable from outside.

I"m unable to connect `

```
shell failed: ssh connection failed: 'Timeout connecting to 192.168.64.6'
```

Why does this not work? How can I make it work? Would a different VPN client be preferred?

Comment: Does your VM use bridged adapter?

Comment: Yes it uses bridge100. Although i don't have a great deal of information on the ramifications of this. Any docs you could point to would be great. I have got the VPN connected by disabling the firewall, but that leaves the killswitch feature unavaliable